# Is my substitution solution to this recurrence correct?

Tags: math, complexity-theory, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

I have a recurrence relation, it is like the following:

T(e<sup>n</sup>) = 2(T(e<sup>n-1</sup>)) + e<sup>n</sup>, where e is the natural logarithm.

To solve this and find a Θ bound, i tried the following: I put k=e<sup>n</sup>, and the equation transforms into:

T(k)=2T(k/e)+k

Then, i try to use the master theorem. According to master theorem, a=2, b=e>2 and f(k)=k. So, we have the case where f(k)=Ω(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a+ε</sup>) for some ε>0, thus we have T(k)=Θ(f(k))=Θ(k). Then put k=n, we have T(n)=Θ(n). Does my solution have any mistakes?

Comment: Removed homework tag - ["This tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. Please do NOT add this tag to questions."](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info).

Comment: What is induction basis T(e^0)?

Comment: Seems correct, though a bit weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work through this one step at a time.

You have the recurrence

> T(e<sup>n</sup>) = 2 T(e<sup>n-1</sup>) + e<sup>n</sup>

Now, let's do a variable substitution.  Define k = e<sup>n</sup>.  Then we get

> T(k) = 2T(k / e) + k

In this case, using the Master Theorem, we get that a = 2, b = e, and f(k) = k.  Since logb a = ln 2 < 1 and f(k) = Θ(k), according to the Master Theorem the recurrence solves to S(k) = Θ(k).

If we now set k = n', where n' is the actual input to the function, then we get that T(n') = Θ(n), and we're done.  So yes, the math checks out.

Hope this helps!